# Nginx $http_x_forwarded_for not always being set

Tags: nginx, http-headers, rate-limiting

I've noticed in our access logs that sometimes, the `$http_x_forwarded_for` variable has not been set, and instead, the correct IP is the one set to `$remote_addr`. Is it possible to set `$http_x_forwarded_for` as `$remote_addr`, when it doesn't otherwise exist?

Basically, the following **psuedo code**, in nginx logic:

`if($http_x_forwarded_for == null) $http_x_forwarded_for = $remote_addr`

I base some limit req zones on the `$http_x_forwarded_for`, so I think this issue could be why it doesn't always take effect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd hazard a guess that you've got [ngx_http_realip_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) enabled and not all of your proxies' IPs are listed as trusted.

Comment: How would I find out if a module has been enabled?

Comment: `nginx -V` will tell you which ones are installed. You'd want to look for the various config variables like `set_real_ip_from` in your `.conf` files to see if it's **used** anywhere.

Comment: I think the issue is that the traffic that does not have `$http_forwarded_for` set, hasn't come through the load balancer.